# Django. File field name

Tags: python, django, file, python-imaging-library

Django 1.7, Pillow 2.7.

I need to use same file name for different files in my file field.

Django model:

```
class FileStorage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Code:

```
item = FileStorage.objects.get(id=1)

image_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))
new_image.save(image_buffer, 'JPEG')
image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(image_buffer, 'image', 'test.jpg', 'image/jpeg', image_buffer.len, None)

item.image.save('test.jpg', image_file)

print item.image.name
# hm4730iiecd8tw2.jpg

image_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
new_image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))
new_image.save(image_buffer, 'JPEG')
image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(image_buffer, 'image', 'test.jpg', 'image/jpeg', image_buffer.len, None)

item.image.save('test.jpg', image_file)

print item.image.name
# 2ji9eni7ywqqndf.jpg
```

I'm a little not clear why Django is not keep my file name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should define `upload_to` option to your ImageField:

```
class FileStorage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/", null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: upload_to attribute is not affect on the file name. I'm not clear why django use autogenerated file name when I use 'test.jpg' for file name.